# CS50 - Filter Edges 4x4 Test Case not working

Tags: c, cs50

I've been doing CS50, and I'm doing Filter right now. However, I'm having trouble with the 4x4 test case for Edges. I've done every other test case successfully, but only 4x4 doesn't work.

Here is the link to the info on the program: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/filter/more/

My code is quite messy, but the main trouble I'm having is why does it work for 3x3, but not 4x4?

https://pastebin.com/jXkmH9CH

Maybe it is because of the way it detects whether the pixel is over 255 or not? (doing this to stop getting error messages saying i can't send this post)

```
for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
    {
    for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
        {
            if (temp_arrayred[x][y] > 255)
            {
                temp_arrayred[x][y] = 255;
            }
            else if (temp_arraygreen[x][y] > 255)
            {
                temp_arrayblue[x][y] = 255;
            }
            else if (temp_arrayblue[x][y] > 255)
            {
                temp_arrayblue[x][y] = 255;
            }

            image[x][y].rgbtRed = temp_arrayred[x][y];
            image[x][y].rgbtGreen = temp_arraygreen[x][y];
            image[x][y].rgbtBlue = temp_arrayblue[x][y];
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

I've tried going through the code multiple times over, writing it down and checking the logic. I think it is alright. But obviously, I probably messed something.

Comment: There's such an insane amount of code duplication here (in your code on pastebin), it's unsurprising that you're having trouble. The code is basically impossible for a human to read. To do image convolution, you just need two extra loops. You can set the horizontal and vertical bounds of those loops independently, depending on your edge proximity.

Comment: This is no place to use `if/else`... Each colour is independent of the others.

Comment: I cannot access your linked code. Please add everything needed to investigate your issue, into the question. What is `temp_array`? My assumption is, that it is of the same type as the `image` array, which means it provides a `uint8_t` per pixel. In that case, how would `temp_arrayblue[x][y] > 255` ever be possible to be true? If you have an overflow, it already happened at that place.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: I think you missed the last paragraph in the [edges](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/filter/more/#edges) problem statement: *"There are many ways to handle pixels at the edge, but for the purposes of this problem, we’ll ask you to treat the image **as if there was a 1 pixel solid black border around the edge of the image**: therefore, trying to access a pixel past the edge of the image should be treated as a solid black pixel (values of 0 for each of red, green, and blue). This will effectively ignore those pixels from our calculations of Gx and Gy."*

Answer (score 0):

After being boggled by the code you linked to, it seemed to be an interesting way to handle the task...

You've created 9 separate blocks with the `if/else` ladder, then put code into each block to handle accessing ALL of the legitimate neighbouring cells... That's quite a bit of code (and incredibly error prone!) My congratulations to you as I couldn't detect an incorrect cell reference in your code. (This suggests the problem likely *was* the **exclusive** `if/else` ladder in the code of your post.)

This does present, however, an opportunity to think about solving this assignment in an atypical way. The following **untested** code is the result of some time spent on the keyboard. I hope I didn't drop anything on the floor...

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) {
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width]; // second "canvas" to store results
    enum {
        gxUL = -1, gxUN = 0, gxUR = 1, // can be enum when handled this way
        gxNL = -2, gxNN = 0, gxNR = 2,
        gxDL = -1, gxDN = 0, gxDR = 1,
    };

    enum {
        gyUL = -1, gyUN = -2, gyUR = -1,
        gyNL =  0, gyNN =  0, gyNR =  0,
        gyDL =  1, gyDN =  2, gyDR =  1,
    };

#define R   rgbtRed // shorter names mean less to read and more obvious if wrong
#define G   rgbtGreen
#define B   rgbtBlue

    // Loop through all pixels, handling "self" and up to 8 "neighbours"
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

            // 1: Self - easy...
            int gx = gxNN, gy = gyNN;
            RGBTRIPLE p = image[ i + 0 ][ j + 0 ];
            int gxR = p.R * gx, gxG = p.G * gx, gxB = p.B * gx;
            int gyR = p.R * gy, gyG = p.G * gy, gyB = p.B * gy;

            // 2: Above - exclude top row
            if (i > 0) {
                gx = gxUN, gy = gyUN;
                p = image[ i - 1 ][ j + 0 ];
                gxR += p.R * gx;    gxG += p.G * gx;    gxB += p.B * gx;
                gyR += p.R * gy;    gyG += p.G * gy;    gyB += p.B * gy;
            }

            // 3: Below - exclude bottom row
            if (i < height - 1) {
                gx = gxDN, gy = gyDN;
                p = image[ i + 1 ][ j + 0 ];
                gxR += p.R * gx;    gxG += p.G * gx;    gxB += p.B * gx;
                gyR += p.R * gy;    gyG += p.G * gy;    gyB += p.B * gy;
            }

            // 4: To the Right - exclude right column
            if (j < width - 1) {
                p = image[ i + 0 ][ j + 1 ];
                gx = gxNL, gy = gyNL;
                gxR += p.R * gx;    gxG += p.G * gx;    gxB += p.B * gx;
                gyR += p.R * gy;    gyG += p.G * gy;    gyB += p.B * gy;
            }

            // 5: To the Left - exclude left column
            if (j > 0) {
                p = image[ i + 0 ][ j - 1 ];
                gx = gxNR, gy = gyNR;
                gxR += p.R * gx;    gxG += p.G * gx;    gxB += p.B * gx;
                gyR += p.R * gy;    gyG += p.G * gy;    gyB += p.B * gy;
            }

            // 6: Above Left - exclude top row and left margin
            if (i > 0 && j > 0) {
                p = image[ i - 1 ][ j - 1 ];
                gx = gxUL, gy = gyUL;
                gxR += p.R * gx;    gxG += p.G * gx;    gxB += p.B * gx;
                gyR += p.R * gy;    gyG += p.G * gy;    gyB += p.B * gy;
            }

            // 7: Above Right - exclude top row and right margin
            if (i > 0 && j != width - 1) {
                p = image[ i - 1 ][ j + 1 ];
                gx = gxUR, gy = gyUR;
                gxR += p.R * gx;    gxG += p.G * gx;    gxB += p.B * gx;
                gyR += p.R * gy;    gyG += p.G * gy;    gyB += p.B * gy;
            }

            // 8: Below Left: exclude bottom row and left margin
            if (i < height - 1 && j > 0) {
                p = image[ i + 1 ][ j - 1 ];
                gx = gxDL, gy = gyDL;
                gxR += p.R * gx;    gxG += p.G * gx;    gxB += p.B * gx;
                gyR += p.R * gy;    gyG += p.G * gy;    gyB += p.B * gy;
            }

            // 9: Below Right: exclude bottom row and right margin
            if (i < height - 1 && j < width - 1) {
                p = image[ i + 1 ][ j + 1 ];
                gx = gxDR, gy = gyDR;
                gxR += p.R * gx;    gxG += p.G * gx;    gxB += p.B * gx;
                gyR += p.R * gy;    gyG += p.G * gy;    gyB += p.B * gy;
            }

            gxR = round( sqrt( gxR * gxR + gyR * gyR ) );
            gxG = round( sqrt( gxG * gxG + gyG * gyG ) );
            gxB = round( sqrt( gxB * gxB + gyB * gyB ) );

            // Each colour is independent, not exclusive
            copy[x][y].R = (gxR > 255) ? 255 : gxR;
            copy[x][y].G = (gxG > 255) ? 255 : gxG;
            copy[x][y].B = (gxG > 255) ? 255 : gxB;
        }
    }

    memcpy( image, copy, sizeof image );
}
```

**EDIT:**
Because this is a novel way to address this problem, I've been tempted to make another pass at the code. This is even more compact (although it involves a bit more processing.) (Again, untested.)

```
typedef struct {
    int xR, xG, xB;
    int yR, yG, yB;
} K_t; // post-Sobel accumulators, x & y for each colour

// helper function that could be made into a macro
static void go( RGBTRIPLE p, int x, int y, K_t *k ) {
    k->xR += x * p.rgbtRed; k->xG += x * p.rgbtGreen; k->xB += x * p.rgbtBlue;
    k->yR += y * p.rgbtRed; k->yG += y * p.rgbtGreen; k->yB += y * p.rgbtBlue;
}

void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) {
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width]; // second "canvas" to store results
    const size_t row0 = 0, rowN = height-1; // terse names for boundaries
    const size_t col0 = 0, colN = width-1;

    enum {
        xUL = -1, xUN = 0, xUR = 1, // the "Sobel grid" values
        xNL = -2, xNN = 0, xNR = 2,
        xDL = -1, xDN = 0, xDR = 1,

        yUL = -1, yUN = -2, yUR = -1,
        yNL =  0, yNN =  0, yNR =  0,
        yDL =  1, yDN =  2, yDR =  1,
    };

    // Loop through all pixels, handling "self" and up to 8 "neighbours"
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            K_t k = { 0 };
                                        go( image[i + 0][j + 0], xNN, yNN, &k ); // Self - easy...
            if( i > row0             )  go( image[i - 1][j + 0], xUN, yUN, &k ); // ^^ w/o top
            if( i < rowN             )  go( image[i + 1][j + 0], xDN, yDN, &k ); // vv w/o bottom
            if(             j < colN )  go( image[i + 0][j + 1], xNL, yNL, &k ); // >> w/o right
            if(             j > col0 )  go( image[i + 0][j - 1], xNR, yNR, &k ); // << w/o left
            if( i > row0 && j > col0 )  go( image[i - 1][j - 1], xUL, yUL, &k ); // ^< w/o top or left
            if( i > row0 && j < colN )  go( image[i - 1][j + 1], xUR, yUR, &k ); // ^> w/o top or right
            if( i < rowN && j > col0 )  go( image[i + 1][j - 1], xDL, yDL, &k ); // v< w/o bottom or left
            if( i < rowN && j < colN )  go( image[i + 1][j + 1], xDR, yDR, &k ); // v> w/o bottom or right

            k.xR = round( sqrt( k.xR * k.xR + k.yR * k.yR ) );
            k.xG = round( sqrt( k.xG * k.xG + k.yG * k.yG ) );
            k.xB = round( sqrt( k.xB * k.xB + k.yB * k.yB ) );

            copy[x][y].rgbtRed   = (k.xR > 255) ? 255 : k.xR;
            copy[x][y].rgbtGreen = (k.xG > 255) ? 255 : k.xG;
            copy[x][y].rgbtBlue  = (k.xB > 255) ? 255 : k.xB;
        }

    memcpy( image, copy, sizeof image );
}
```

It's worth noting that the centre pixel, of any 3x3, is irrelevant as the Sobel grid multipliers, both x and y, are 0.

Comment: I did a quick reflection on that code that I thought was wrong and I was realised that I was a massive idiot and saw that if temp_arraygreen was greater than 255, I assigned the temp_arrayblue value instead to 0. However, this did not fix my issue. Any tips?
Also, interesting code, it took me a long time to fully piece together how each piece of code worked together.

Comment: Nvm, I just solved the problem!

Comment: "_it took me a long time to fully piece together..._" The code in your question must have taken a long time to produce, too... Honestly, it is an interesting approach, and lead to me trying to adapt it as per the code in this answer... Lesson: programmers are not "_paid by the pound_" for the amount of code they produce. Tip: If it feels like you are using too much copy/paste, then it's time to stop and find a better solution.